# Create directories if not exists in windows with for loop and list

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line

I'm fairly new to batch files (and I just want the basic batch files, no scripts like powershell, etc.)

As part of our configuration management, I'd like to create a number of directories if it does not exist, e.g. pseudo code

```
myDir[1] = 'd:\logging\Folder1'
myDir[2] = 'd:\logging\Folder2'
...
myDir[9] = 'd:\logging\Folder9'

for i=1 to 9
  if not exist myDir[i] mkdir myDir[i]
```

I'm okay with the directories in the array being hardcoded

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you even need an array. It seems like a list would work just fine.

```
for %%F in (
  "d:\logging\Folder1"
  "d:\logging\Folder2"
  ... etc.
  "d:\logging\FolderN"
) do if not exist "%%~F\" mkdir "%%~F"
```

I use quotes around the folder paths just in case any of the names contain spaces or poison characters.

The trailing `\` in the IF NOT EXIST test forces it to only match folders and not files.

Comment: That's awesome! What does the ~ in %%~F mean?

Comment: @Raymond - It removes any enclosing quotes, if they exist. Of course I turn around and put them back. So it ends up being a safe way to guarantee the path is quoted, whether or not you include the quotes in the original list. It's probably silly on my part. It most likely will always work just as well with `%%F` without enclosing quotes beyond what were in the original list.

Answer (score 0):

This is another method.  The `2>nul` just keeps the screen clear if any of the folders already exist.

The `1,1,9` means to start at 1 and count in steps of 1 up to 9

```
@echo off
for /L %%a in (1,1,9) do md "d:\logging\Folder%%a" 2>nul
```